# Scala folding tuples

Tags: scala, dictionary, fold

```
Map(Mary -> List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414))):
  Map[String, List[(String, Int)]]
```

How can I fold the maps to produce something like

```
Map("Mary" -> List(("Mary", 7065+2604+1414))):
  Map[String, List[(String, Int)]]
```

?

Comment: I assume `7065+2604+1414` is a `String`?

Comment: I made a few edits under the assumption that it was actually the summation, apologies if I'm mistaken.

Comment: No it should be an int, just didnt bother adding them up so it would be easy to understand

Answer (score 1):

For your special case you can use this

```
map.map { case (k, v) => k -> v.map(_._2).sum }
```

but generally below code works for everything even if keys are different

Do groupby with first item in the tuple and then collapse the list which is the value of the resultant map after groupby

```
val list = Map("Mary")
list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => v(0)._1 -> v.map(_._2).sum}
```

**Scala REPL**

```
 scala> val list = map("Mary")
 list: List[(String, Int)] = List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414))

 scala> list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => v(0)._1 -> v.map(_._2).sum}
 res11: Map[String, Int] = Map("Mary" -> 11083)

 scala> val map =  Map("Mary" -> List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414)))
 map: Map[String, List[(String, Int)]] = Map("Mary" -> List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414)))

 scala> val list = map("Mary")
 list: List[(String, Int)] = List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414))

 scala> list.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => v(0)._1 -> v.map(_._2).sum}
 res14: Map[String, Int] = Map("Mary" -> 11083)
```

Answer (score 0):

You group by the the key's, then fold on the values:

```
scala> val input = Map("Mary" -> List(("Mary", 1), ("Mary", 2), ("Mary", 3)))
res1: Iterable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(String, Int)]]] = List(Map(Mary -> List((Mary,1), (Mary,2), (Mary,3))))

scala> input.values.map(_.groupBy(_._1).map { case (k, v) => (k -> v.map(_._2).foldLeft(0)(_ + _))})
res7: Iterable[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] = List(Map(Mary -> 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val data = Map("Mary" -> List(("Mary", 7065), ("Mary", 2604), ("Mary", 1414)))

data map { case (x,y) => (x, y.foldLeft(0)((acc, elem) => acc + elem._2)) }
```

This results in the Map:
`scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(Mary -> 11083)`

Comment: This answer is correct for the "old" version of the question in the way it was asked.